# Looking for a sci-fi kids book essentially about zombies, but they weren’t called that

Tags: story-identification, aliens, zombie-apocalypse

I read the book in middle school so 2012ish. It was a small town but something happened to them and only some lived. The rest basically turned into zombies and they were “mapping” zombies that only walked around and appeared to be mapping everything. Later on, possibly in the next book, they find out that whatever it is is makin the zombie people pregnant.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember the cover art, or the names of any characters or places?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what the "mapping" means?